# Change wpf user control using devexpress mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, devexpress-wpf

I'm trying to change the `UserControl` in my mainwindow.
I'm using devpress's poco viewmodels.

The main window displays except for where the loginView should be it displays
"LoginViewModel_xxxxxx"

The `LoginView.xaml` is a `UserControl`.

I have

MainWindow.xaml

```
    <Grid Row="1">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
    </Grid>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public virtual object CurrentViewModel { get; set; }

public static MainWindowViewModel Create()
{
   return ViewModelSource.Create(() => new MainWindowViewModel());
}
protected MainWindowViewModel()
{
   CurrentViewModel = LoginViewModel.Create();
}
```

LoginViewModel.cs

```
public static LoginViewModel Create()
{
    return ViewModelSource.Create(() => new LoginViewModel());
}

protected LoginViewModel()
{
    //unrelated code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to define a `DataTemplate` for the `LoginViewModel`:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LoginViewModel}">
            <local:LoginView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Just a note to whoever uses this; if your `ContentControl` can be any number of different view-model types, you need to have multiple DataTemplates defined in the resources, one for each type.